Sorting Issue with Date Columns in Power BI
Problem Description:
I'm encountering difficulties with sorting date columns in Power BI, and I'm seeking assistance to resolve this issue. Specifically, I have two columns in my dataset related to task due dates: 'task_due_text' and 'task_due_sort'. When attempting to sort 'task_due_text' based on 'task_due_sort', I encounter an error stating, "We can't sort the 'task_due_text' by 'task_due_sort'. There can't be more than one value 'task_due_sort' for the same value in 'task_due_text'."
Despite ensuring the unique correspondence between the two columns, I'm experiencing difficulties in sorting them properly in Power BI.
task_due_text   task_due_sort
Nov 2026    202611
Dec 2025    202512
Nov 2025    202511
Jan 2025    202501
Dec 2024    202412
Nov 2024    202411
Oct 2024    202410
Sep 2024    202409
Aug 2024    202408
Jul 2024    202407
Jun 2024    202406
May 2024    202405
Apr 2024    202404
Mar 2024    202403
Feb 2024    202402
Jan 2024    202401
Dec 2023    202312
Nov 2023    202311
Jan 2023    202301

task_due_text = FORMAT('Task Table'[task_due_date], "mmm yyyy")
task_due_sort = YEAR('Task Table'[task_due_date]) * 100 + MONTH('Task Table'[task_due_date])
Steps Taken:

Verified the unique correspondence between 'task_due_text' and 'task_due_sort' to ensure data integrity.
Checked for hidden characters or whitespace in the 'task_due_sort' column that might affect sorting.
Confirmed that both columns have compatible data types and match their intended use - 'task_due_text' is set to Text and I've tried both Text and Whole Number data types for 'task_due_sort' with no change in behavior.
Experimented with sorting both columns independently to understand the behavior - I can sort 'task_due_sort' based on 'task_due_text'

Desired Outcome:
I'm seeking guidance on resolving the sorting issue and achieving the desired sorting behavior in Power BI. Ideally, I want to sort 'task_due_sort' based on the numerical representation of the date while maintaining the unique correspondence with 'task_due_text'.

for a second I thought this was going to be challenging. Turns out it wasn't.
Here's the PowerQuery:
    let
    Source = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary(File.Contents("C:\Users\User\Desktop\bad dates.txt"), null, null, 1252)}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1.1", type text}, {"Column1.2", type text}}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"task_due_text  ", type date}, {"task_due_sort", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"

And it was all pointy-clicky stuff, too. No hard Powerquery functions or anything. Get Data > from Text file and off you go.

for a second I thought this was going to be challenging. Turns out it wasn't.
Here's the PowerQuery:
    let
    Source = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary(File.Contents("C:\Users\User\Desktop\bad dates.txt"), null, null, 1252)}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1.1", type text}, {"Column1.2", type text}}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"task_due_text  ", type date}, {"task_due_sort", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"

And it was all pointy-clicky stuff, too. No hard Powerquery functions or anything. Get Data > from Text file and off you go.  About the only way to make this hard was to skip the conversion to Date part. But when I imported the text file, PowerQuery figured out it was a date. So I'm not sure what's going on on your end.

Wow...I ran into the same issue with another project and finally found an answer. It seems there is a cache issue? This table in this new project had unique values in both columns, again, and there seemed to be no reason to be getting this error. The answer was to close Power Bi and open it back up. Sort by Column worked once I did this...smh.
This is where I got the idea:
https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Yet-another-Sort-by-another-Column-error/m-p/3889791#M1251137
